# Pandas two dataframes with multiplecolumns into a single boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boxplot

So I have 2 dataframes each with multiple columns:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 0.11 | 1.12 |  | 12.32 |
| 1.48 | 0.03 |  | 0.32 | 17.85 |
|  |  | 0.56 | 0.95 | 8.35 |
| 0.09 | 2.31 | 0.32 | 1.04 | 5.46 |

The other one is similar to this one, filled with some other data. I need to plot these 2 dataframes on 1 plot. Each column being a different x-axis index value. I am using the pandas.DataFrame.boxplot() method as it is the only method that truly plots my data without skipping anything (matplotlib.boxplot() seems to plot only a part of the data, no idea why).

The issue is that calling multiple df.boxplot() one after another causes an error:

```
File "analysis_script.py", line 387, in <module>
    df.boxplot()
  File "pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 516, in boxplot_frame
    return plot_backend.boxplot_frame(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\boxplot.py", line 458, in boxplot_frame
    ax = boxplot(
         ^^^^^^^^
  File "pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\boxplot.py", line 437, in boxplot
    result = plot_group(columns, data.values.T, ax, **kwds)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "bpandas\plotting\_matplotlib\boxplot.py", line 376, in plot_group
    assert remainder == 0, remainder
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AssertionError: 1
```

Here's the section of my code:

```
match index:
    case 0:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        df.boxplot()
    case 1:
        df.boxplot()

        min_y = min_y_8h - 0.25 * abs(min_y_8h)
        max_y = max_y_8h + 1.25 * abs(max_y_8h)

        x_ticks = plt.xticks()[0]
        x_labels = [str(int(tick)) for tick in x_ticks if int(tick) % 3 == 0]
        plt.xticks(x_ticks[x_ticks % 3 == 0], x_labels, rotation=45)
        plt.xlim(2.5, 23.5)
        plt.ylim(min_y, max_y)
        plt.show()
        plt.close()
```

It's run in a loop so the df variable is a different df in each iteration and the index variable serves many functions, in this case it's used to monitor which data is being plotted.

Answer (score 0):

The `AssertionError: 1` is likely due to a mismatch between the number of columns between the different dataframes you're creating with the loop.

I've tried to reproduce the problem and did get the same issue with a couple of minimal dataframes. I've tried to solve this issue - **to plot boxplots from multiple dataframes on the same axes** using `matplotlib`'s boxplot and it seems to do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# random dfs
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=['E', 'F', 'G'])

dfs = [df1, df2]

# Create a figure and axes outside the loop
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Initial position for the first dataframe's boxplot
position = 1

for df in dfs:
    # plot the dataframe using Matplotlib's boxplot
    ax.boxplot([df[col].dropna() for col in df.columns], positions=range(position, position + len(df.columns)))

    # update position
    position += len(df.columns)

ax.set_xticks(range(1, position))
ax.set_xticklabels(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], rotation=45)
ax.set_xlim(0.5, position - 0.5)

plt.show()
```

We don't have what's going on outside you're loop but it should look something like this with using this approach. This is not a working example as I don't have the data your using but it's a skeleton based on your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Assuming 'dfs' is a list of your dataframes
dfs = [...] 

# Initialize the position for the first boxplot
position = 1

for index, df in enumerate(dfs):
    match index:
        case 0:
            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            # Plot using Matplotlib's boxplot
            ax.boxplot([df[col].dropna() for col in df.columns], positions=range(position, position + len(df.columns)))
            # Update the position for the next dataframe
            position += len(df.columns)

        case 1:
            # Plot using Matplotlib's boxplot
            ax.boxplot([df[col].dropna() for col in df.columns], positions=range(position, position + len(df.columns)))
            # Update the position for the next dataframe
            position += len(df.columns)

            # Your additional settings
            min_y = min_y_8h - 0.25 * abs(min_y_8h) 
            max_y = max_y_8h + 1.25 * abs(max_y_8h)

            x_ticks = ax.get_xticks()
            x_labels = [str(int(tick)) for tick in x_ticks if int(tick) % 3 == 0]
            ax.set_xticks(x_ticks[x_ticks % 3 == 0])
            ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels, rotation=45)
            ax.set_xlim(2.5, position - 0.5)
            ax.set_ylim(min_y, max_y)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

I've also taken the `show()` and `close()` outside the loop as you try to generate a single plot from multiple dfs which makes more sense.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for this! I know the question is written in a chaotic way so I truly appreciate the time you took to help me with this. I implemented your solution and the code runs, I get no errors and am able to get a plot with proper data BUT there only is data from the case 0 section of my code. To double check this, I color-coded the graphs, case 0 being red, case 1 being green and the data from case 1 is not plotted. Any ideas on why that might be?

EDIT: I am a dummy and have limited the x axis in a way that makes it impossible for the case 1 data to plot. Have adjusted it now.

Comment: So did it get it working? just out of curiosity...

Comment: Yes, I did! Thanks a lot. Would upvote your answer but I can't :))))))))))